# Problema con poner visible un item del navigation draw que se crea por defecto

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment

tengo un problema que no se solucionar y creo que estoy pasando todas las variables correctamente.
He creado un Navigation draw, este se crea por defecto cuando creas un activity navigation draw.

Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando el usuario sea igual a "admin@admin.com" que el navigation draw muestre el item, el item en el xml le he puesto visible = false

Os dejo el código del onCreate del navigationdrawer.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    carritoDataSource = new LocalCartDataSource(CarritoBaseDatos.getInstance(this).carritoDAO());
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.carritocompra);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            navController.navigate(R.id.nav_cart);
        }
    });
    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_menu, R.id.nav_mostrarpedido,
            R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_cart, R.id.nav_lista_comida)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this );
    navigationView.bringToFront();
    countCartItem();


    //hidedrawermenu();
}
```

Ahora he hecho una función que es para hacerlo visible

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

private void hidedrawermenu(){
    mAuth =FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail().equals("admin@admin.com")){
        navigationView.findViewById(R.id.nav_tools).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

El error que me aparece en el Log es el siguiente:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.myapplication.MenuActivity.hidedrawermenu(MenuActivity.java:107)
        at com.example.myapplication.MenuActivity.onCreate(MenuActivity.java:102)
```

Comment: Te está diciendo que `navigationView` es `null` en la función `hidedrawermenu`. En `onCreate` defines una variable **local** con ese nombre, pero dado que es local a `onCreate`, no es la misma que usas en `hidedrawermenu` y esa parece que es `null`. Parece que tienes también una variable en la clase con el mismo nombre y te estás despistando.

Comment: Lo acabo de conseguir, muchas gracias, he publicado la respuesta ya

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he conseguido.

```
private void hidedrawermenu(){
        mAuth =FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail().equals("admin@admin.com")){
            navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            Menu nav_menu = navigationView.getMenu();
            nav_menu.findItem(R.id.nav_mostrarpedido).setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Parece que mi suposición era cierta. La mejor solución es no redefinir la variable en onCreate, solo darle valor, y usar la variable de la clase. Solo una variable

Answer (score -1):

Lo ideal es enviar la vista de la cual se obtendrá la referecia:

```
private void hidedrawermenu(NavigationView navigationView){
    mAuth =FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail().equals("admin@admin.com")){
        navigationView.findViewById(R.id.nav_tools).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

de esta forma podrías llamar el método enviando la vista en donde se encuentre el navigationView:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    ...
    ...
    ...
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
   ...
   ...
    hidedrawermenu(navigationView );
}
```

---

Otra solución es buscar la referencia dentro del mismo método, asegurando usar el contexto, en este caso si te encuentras en la misma activity usa únicamente `findViewById()` :

```
private void hidedrawermenu(NavigationView navigationView){
    mAuth =FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail().equals("admin@admin.com")){
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.findViewById(R.id.nav_tools).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```